# Dual Monitor from 1 VGA and 1 DVI port

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I currently have the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650, these are the specs I think will be most relevant:

```
Display Support:
4 displaysMulti Monitor
2560x1600
4096x21603Maximum Digital Resolution
2048x1536Maximum VGA Resolution
YesHDCP
YesHDMI4
One Dual Link DVI-I, One Dual Link DVI-D, One Mini HDMIStandard Display Connectors
InternalAudio Input for HDMI
```

I am using the DVI port for my iiyama monitor (this has HDMI, DVI and VGA ports), but thinking of investing into another monitor (identical to the first). Would my graphics card work by using some sort of splitter, or would I need to use one DVI cable for the first monitor and one VGA cable for the second monitor?

*Please note, I do not want to simply have two screens that are mirrors, I need them to be an extended desktop type setup*

Comment: What is the monitors own resolution, or native resolution?  (post the monitor model) You have 2 digital connections the DVI (or is it 2 DVI?) and the HDMI, it would be preferable to use digital connections for digital monitors when ever possible. so potentially you could test both connection methods now (dvi and hdmi), using the one monitor in each. You should not need any additional items besides cables to connect the other monitor.

Comment: I tried using both cables on my existing monitor, and it worked fine!
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to simply have two screens that are mirrors,
>   I need them to be an extended desktop type setup
>
> Would my graphics card work by using some sort of splitter,

No. If you use a splitter then you split the identical signal in two and you end up with a mirror.

> or would I need to use one DVI cable for the first monitor and one VGA cable for the second monitor?

You want to use two different outputs. And if possible you want to use digital output. You list two dual ink DVI outputs. If at all possible I would use those to connect to both monitors.

(Skip VGA. It is an ancient (1985) standard with all the drawbacks from tbat era.  The only reason why people still use it is that many cheap devices have it. This is because VGA is free to use. Unlike VDI (which followed VGA). Unlike HDMI (which is sort of DVI+audio and which since has been supassed by DP.)